# How to Include a Loop Template File in a Plugin

Tags: plugins, php, templates

I am trying to include a template file into a loop i made in a shortcode, in a plugin. Everything shows up fine when the template is actually pasted into the loop, but to make things neat I want to separate it into it's own file.

I created a file called `hi.php` and it's located in a plugin subfolder called `parts`.

Here is the code I place in the loop, but it is not loading the template:

`include plugins_url( '/parts/hi.php', __FILE__ );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it like this:

```
// Inclusion of additional php files
define( 'MYPLUG_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );

require_once( MYPLUG_DIR . 'hi.php' );
```

It lets you use that more easily if you have to include several files.